# How to open Markup tools faster in Preview

Tags: macos, preview, big-sur

Since a recent update to Preview (Big Sur?), the edit button is two clicks away on "narrow" images:

[image]

How can I force Preview, regardless of the image dimensions, to always open a window that is wide enough for the Markup button to be only one click away?

[image]

In fact, even better would be if someone has a method that can just open the Markup options by default:

[image]

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, just customize the **Toolbar** moving the **Markup** _button_ to be the first _item_ to the right of the _filename_ in the **Toolbar**.

Comment: @user3439894 oh yeah, that works